# jquery/php/mysql purchase ordering system help needed

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, database, get

i'm attempting to make a purchase ordering system for work in php, mysql and jquery. I've got a "running total" working great but i've come to the point where if the user is happy and wants to proceed to order the products they've selected i want to take the items at the bottom of the screen (attached picture to see what i mean) and send the values to a php script which will insert them into a db called "orders". what i imagined happening was they press "save" and jquery grabs all the values from the rows in the table at the bottom and sends them via "GET" to the waiting PHP, the php would insert all data it receives into the db, all with a unique "id" so people can pull back orders at a later date...I know what i want to do but i'm struggling to plan out the specific mysql querys/jquery stuff! Any help appreciated! [image: Screenshot of current progress]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't trust the data in the table enough to pull the running total or list prices back from it. A user with firebug for example could easily lower the price of their order.

You really want to store the cart in the users session so you can maintain an accurate account of the total on the server side with prices you can trust because the user cannot change them. Never trust data coming back from the front end. When the user adds an item to the cart ask the server for the price by `product_id` rather than using jQuery to grab it from the DOM.

When the user submits an order you don't pass anything using jQuery you just trigger a PHP script that will use the cart stored in the session to process the order.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Whether i'm being naive or not, i meant the cart is for work, as in its our employees using it to place orders to send to suppliers (but i understand your reservations). If, hypothetically, i was to send values from the jQuery, how would you go about doing it, send them in a long hyperlink or store them in an array then send that array to the php?

Comment: I still would not do it that way no matter who is using the system. But if you have no choice then I would store them in a JS object or array and send them to the PHP script using a jQuery `$.post()`. Don't do it though - store the cart in the session instead. Try to keep your display and data separate.